# Save PDF file as a single image

Tags: automator, pdf, graphics, file-conversion

I would like to create an automator that converts each page to an image, combines all the images vertically and finally saves the result as an image. I don't know how to combine the images. Could someone guide me through this?

Input: Multiple page PDF

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the end result to be?  It's a bit unclear at this point (a sample would be a great help).

Comment: Possible, but the easiest option would be to use imagemagick. See https://superuser.com/questions/316132/appending-images-vertically-in-imagemagick

Comment: @user2707001 You are right! The Imagemagick is the solution for everything, but I am searching for a way to create an Automator.  Is it possible to use Imagemagic inside an Automator?

Comment: @01000110 Yes, with Apple Script (`do shell script "myshellscript"`) or Terminal Action.

Comment: @jmh It is mentioned in the question! The input is a PDF file. ; )